# How to fix (Error: parsererror errorThrown: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < )using java action

Tags: javascript, json, action

```
var duepaymentDebtDate = "02/02/2015";
 $.getJSON("checkDateAjaxtoJSON.action",{"duepaymentDebtDate":duepaymentDebtDate},
     function(json){

         alert(json);
     }).error(function(jqXHR,textStatus, errorThrown){

            console.log("Error: " + textStatus + " errorThrown: " + errorThrown);

         });
```

this code I want to do something in my action and `json` doesn't return result and they show message error in console like these :

```
Error: parsererror errorThrown: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

anybody can help me?

Comment: Your server is probably returning html formatted result, instead of plain JSON.

Comment: thank you for your answer but I can't change type to application/json because this script inside the page.

Comment: @AradaPrincessSand No one said anything about `application/json`. Also, what do you mean by "because this script inside the page"?

Comment: @boly38 thank you for your opinion now I follow your advise and it's work now

Comment: Could you consider this question as answered?

Comment: @boly38 yes, I consider this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check server side logs and code.

- Try to surround the "checkDateAjaxtoJSON.action" core business process with a `try/catch`.

Maybe you server-side code is in error too and produce a default error `5xx` html result.